# Joomla and PHPBB3 integration

Tags: php, web, joomla, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm on a current web project, on which there's a working PHPBB3 installation in

(root)/phpbb3

All other files of the page are directly on (root)/ and are manually programmed.

now I have to refactor the whole page with Joomla and want to integrate the PHPBB3 directly into the main page, so that header, menu and footer of the joomla page are still beeing displayed, only the content shall be the PHPBB.

There are no further log in mechansims on my page, so this is not an issue. It's just about an optical integration of the board into the page...is this possible?

If yes, how?

Could you please give me a hint?

greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it before.  There's a component/application called [RokBridge](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbridge) that does basically this.  Note that phpBB isn't running exactly "inside" of Joomla, since that would be disadvantages for performance reasons...